# Have a self extract archive extract to specific folder

Tags: windows, zip, archiving, 7-zip

How can I create a self extracting archive that will extract the contents into a specific folder? Any program or method is acceptable on windows.

Comment: Do you have 7-zip installed on your computer? Also, by specific folder do you mean one that can be specified when extracting?

Comment: I have 7zip, and can create a self extracting archive. And yes by specific folder I mean that I can specify the location of the folder let's say c:\temp .